# Can't set new dimensions for a horizontal page in the middle of document

Tags: latex, pdflatex, overleaf

I have been dealing with this issue for a while now, where I want to insert a table in my document but it's too big.

Here's how I dealt with this step by step:

1. I used:

```
\begin{landscape} 

table

\end{landscape}
```

2. Table still too big (this is where the issues appear). I tried using the 'newgeometry' tool but for some reason Overleaf doesn't have it available, even though I imported the package in the preamble. This is the warning I get: 'Warning: `paperwidth': not available in` \newgeometry'; skipped'.
3. Tried changing the margins instead, but the table still does not fit and in addition, the command '\restoregeometry' is ignored and the rest of the document gets the newly edited margins too.
4. Found the '\pdfpagewidth' command online. I removed the landscape environment thinking that it would suffice to just change the width of the page, but then again, the entire rest of the document changes width.
5. I also tried using '\changepage' but it also didn't do anything to my document

My question is, is there a way to use '\pdfpagewidth' for just one page of my document, in the middle of one of the sections and keeping the number of the table match the other tables in the section, and then restoring the rest of the document to its original format?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Within LaTeX itself, you are not allowed to change paper specification of the same document, such as a dimension or an orientation.
The warning does tell you that.

`landscape` environment of `pdflscape` utilises some tricks to *simulate* landscape, although this is not the same as the `landscape` document settings.
For instance, some length names don't work and as such you have to use `\linewidth` instead of `\textwidth`.

`newgeometry` can alter margins, headers, footers or corresponding skips and separators but again changing paper specs is not allowed.
It also issues a page break, so does `\restoregeometry`.
This means, if you put your table in altered geometry, you have to accept it is going to be on separate pages.

As to the table itself, try to change font size down to `\footnotesize` if necessary but not smaller than that.
You can also change space between columns via `\setlength\tabcolsep{<len>}` or `colsep` in `tabularray`-related environments.
I would avoid applying `\resizebox`, unless it is REALLY a small factor.
If all this fails, this means the table probably needs a thorough redesign or you have to split the table into smaller ones.

---

Alternatively, there are free to use tools to manipulate PDFs such as [pdftk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftk), which can concatenate two separate PDFs.

---

Here's a demo code, which demonstrates usages of `landscape` environment along with altered geometry.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}
\section{First}
\blindtext[2]

Reference to the table \ref{tab:big-table}.

\newgeometry{
    margin=0.75cm,
    noheadfoot, nomarginpar,
    footskip=1.25em,
}
\begin{landscape}
\small
\begin{longtblr}[
        caption = {The very big table here},
        label = {tab:big-table},
        note{$\dag$} = {A note of the big table},
        remark{Note} = {Something important about the table},
    ]{
        width=\linewidth,
        colspec = {@{}X[2] *{19}{X[c]}@{}},
        row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
        column{2-Z} = {colsep=2pt},
        rowhead = 1,
    }
    \toprule
    Names
    & Value & Value & Value & Value & Value
    & Value & Value & Value & Value & Value
    & Value & Value & Value & Value & Value
    & Value & Value & Value & Value \\
    \midrule
    Row name\TblrNote{$\dag$}
    & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567 & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567
    & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 & 1.234 & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 \\
    Row name
    & 5.678 & 9.0 & 123.4 & 56.7 & 8.901 & 2.345 & 6.7 & 890.1 & 23.4 & 5.678
    & 9.012 & 3.4 & 567.8 & 90.1 & 2.345 & 6.789 & 0.1 & 234.5 & 67.8 \\
    Row name
    & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567 & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567
    & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 & 1.234 & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 \\
    Row name
    & 5.678 & 9.0 & 123.4 & 56.7 & 8.901 & 2.345 & 6.7 & 890.1 & 23.4 & 5.678
    & 9.012 & 3.4 & 567.8 & 90.1 & 2.345 & 6.789 & 0.1 & 234.5 & 67.8 \\
    Row name
    & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567 & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567
    & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 & 1.234 & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 \\
    Row name
    & 5.678 & 9.0 & 123.4 & 56.7 & 8.901 & 2.345 & 6.7 & 890.1 & 23.4 & 5.678
    & 9.012 & 3.4 & 567.8 & 90.1 & 2.345 & 6.789 & 0.1 & 234.5 & 67.8 \\
    Row name
    & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567 & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567
    & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 & 1.234 & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 \\
    Row name
    & 5.678 & 9.0 & 123.4 & 56.7 & 8.901 & 2.345 & 6.7 & 890.1 & 23.4 & 5.678
    & 9.012 & 3.4 & 567.8 & 90.1 & 2.345 & 6.789 & 0.1 & 234.5 & 67.8 \\
    Row name
    & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567 & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567
    & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 & 1.234 & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 \\
    Row name
    & 5.678 & 9.0 & 123.4 & 56.7 & 8.901 & 2.345 & 6.7 & 890.1 & 23.4 & 5.678
    & 9.012 & 3.4 & 567.8 & 90.1 & 2.345 & 6.789 & 0.1 & 234.5 & 67.8 \\
    Row name
    & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567 & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567
    & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 & 1.234 & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 \\
    Row name
    & 5.678 & 9.0 & 123.4 & 56.7 & 8.901 & 2.345 & 6.7 & 890.1 & 23.4 & 5.678
    & 9.012 & 3.4 & 567.8 & 90.1 & 2.345 & 6.789 & 0.1 & 234.5 & 67.8 \\
    Row name
    & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567 & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567
    & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 & 1.234 & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 \\
    Row name
    & 5.678 & 9.0 & 123.4 & 56.7 & 8.901 & 2.345 & 6.7 & 890.1 & 23.4 & 5.678
    & 9.012 & 3.4 & 567.8 & 90.1 & 2.345 & 6.789 & 0.1 & 234.5 & 67.8 \\
    Row name
    & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567 & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567
    & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 & 1.234 & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 \\
    Row name
    & 5.678 & 9.0 & 123.4 & 56.7 & 8.901 & 2.345 & 6.7 & 890.1 & 23.4 & 5.678
    & 9.012 & 3.4 & 567.8 & 90.1 & 2.345 & 6.789 & 0.1 & 234.5 & 67.8 \\
    Row name
    & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567 & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567
    & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 & 1.234 & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 \\
    Row name
    & 5.678 & 9.0 & 123.4 & 56.7 & 8.901 & 2.345 & 6.7 & 890.1 & 23.4 & 5.678
    & 9.012 & 3.4 & 567.8 & 90.1 & 2.345 & 6.789 & 0.1 & 234.5 & 67.8 \\
    Row name
    & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567 & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567
    & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 & 1.234 & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 \\
    Row name
    & 5.678 & 9.0 & 123.4 & 56.7 & 8.901 & 2.345 & 6.7 & 890.1 & 23.4 & 5.678
    & 9.012 & 3.4 & 567.8 & 90.1 & 2.345 & 6.789 & 0.1 & 234.5 & 67.8 \\
    Row name
    & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567 & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567
    & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 & 1.234 & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 \\
    Row name
    & 5.678 & 9.0 & 123.4 & 56.7 & 8.901 & 2.345 & 6.7 & 890.1 & 23.4 & 5.678
    & 9.012 & 3.4 & 567.8 & 90.1 & 2.345 & 6.789 & 0.1 & 234.5 & 67.8 \\
    Row name
    & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567 & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567
    & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 & 1.234 & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 \\
    Row name
    & 5.678 & 9.0 & 123.4 & 56.7 & 8.901 & 2.345 & 6.7 & 890.1 & 23.4 & 5.678
    & 9.012 & 3.4 & 567.8 & 90.1 & 2.345 & 6.789 & 0.1 & 234.5 & 67.8 \\
    Row name
    & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567 & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567
    & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 & 1.234 & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 \\
    Row name
    & 5.678 & 9.0 & 123.4 & 56.7 & 8.901 & 2.345 & 6.7 & 890.1 & 23.4 & 5.678
    & 9.012 & 3.4 & 567.8 & 90.1 & 2.345 & 6.789 & 0.1 & 234.5 & 67.8 \\
    Row name
    & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567 & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567
    & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 & 1.234 & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 \\
    Row name
    & 5.678 & 9.0 & 123.4 & 56.7 & 8.901 & 2.345 & 6.7 & 890.1 & 23.4 & 5.678
    & 9.012 & 3.4 & 567.8 & 90.1 & 2.345 & 6.789 & 0.1 & 234.5 & 67.8 \\
    Row name
    & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567 & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567
    & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 & 1.234 & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 \\
    Row name
    & 5.678 & 9.0 & 123.4 & 56.7 & 8.901 & 2.345 & 6.7 & 890.1 & 23.4 & 5.678
    & 9.012 & 3.4 & 567.8 & 90.1 & 2.345 & 6.789 & 0.1 & 234.5 & 67.8 \\
    Row name
    & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567 & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567
    & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 & 1.234 & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 \\
    Row name
    & 5.678 & 9.0 & 123.4 & 56.7 & 8.901 & 2.345 & 6.7 & 890.1 & 23.4 & 5.678
    & 9.012 & 3.4 & 567.8 & 90.1 & 2.345 & 6.789 & 0.1 & 234.5 & 67.8 \\
    Row name
    & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567 & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567
    & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 & 1.234 & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 \\
    Row name
    & 5.678 & 9.0 & 123.4 & 56.7 & 8.901 & 2.345 & 6.7 & 890.1 & 23.4 & 5.678
    & 9.012 & 3.4 & 567.8 & 90.1 & 2.345 & 6.789 & 0.1 & 234.5 & 67.8 \\
    Row name
    & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567 & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567
    & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 & 1.234 & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 \\
    Row name
    & 5.678 & 9.0 & 123.4 & 56.7 & 8.901 & 2.345 & 6.7 & 890.1 & 23.4 & 5.678
    & 9.012 & 3.4 & 567.8 & 90.1 & 2.345 & 6.789 & 0.1 & 234.5 & 67.8 \\
    Row name
    & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567 & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567
    & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 & 1.234 & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 \\
    Row name
    & 5.678 & 9.0 & 123.4 & 56.7 & 8.901 & 2.345 & 6.7 & 890.1 & 23.4 & 5.678
    & 9.012 & 3.4 & 567.8 & 90.1 & 2.345 & 6.789 & 0.1 & 234.5 & 67.8 \\
    Row name
    & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567 & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567
    & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 & 1.234 & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 \\
    Row name
    & 5.678 & 9.0 & 123.4 & 56.7 & 8.901 & 2.345 & 6.7 & 890.1 & 23.4 & 5.678
    & 9.012 & 3.4 & 567.8 & 90.1 & 2.345 & 6.789 & 0.1 & 234.5 & 67.8 \\
    Row name
    & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567 & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567
    & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 & 1.234 & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 \\
    Row name
    & 5.678 & 9.0 & 123.4 & 56.7 & 8.901 & 2.345 & 6.7 & 890.1 & 23.4 & 5.678
    & 9.012 & 3.4 & 567.8 & 90.1 & 2.345 & 6.789 & 0.1 & 234.5 & 67.8 \\
    Row name
    & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567 & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567
    & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 & 1.234 & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 \\
    Row name
    & 5.678 & 9.0 & 123.4 & 56.7 & 8.901 & 2.345 & 6.7 & 890.1 & 23.4 & 5.678
    & 9.012 & 3.4 & 567.8 & 90.1 & 2.345 & 6.789 & 0.1 & 234.5 & 67.8 \\
    Row name
    & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567 & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567
    & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 & 1.234 & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 \\
    Row name
    & 5.678 & 9.0 & 123.4 & 56.7 & 8.901 & 2.345 & 6.7 & 890.1 & 23.4 & 5.678
    & 9.012 & 3.4 & 567.8 & 90.1 & 2.345 & 6.789 & 0.1 & 234.5 & 67.8 \\
    Row name
    & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567 & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567
    & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 & 1.234 & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 \\
    Row name
    & 5.678 & 9.0 & 123.4 & 56.7 & 8.901 & 2.345 & 6.7 & 890.1 & 23.4 & 5.678
    & 9.012 & 3.4 & 567.8 & 90.1 & 2.345 & 6.789 & 0.1 & 234.5 & 67.8 \\
    Row name
    & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567 & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567
    & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 & 1.234 & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 \\
    Row name
    & 5.678 & 9.0 & 123.4 & 56.7 & 8.901 & 2.345 & 6.7 & 890.1 & 23.4 & 5.678
    & 9.012 & 3.4 & 567.8 & 90.1 & 2.345 & 6.789 & 0.1 & 234.5 & 67.8 \\
    Row name
    & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567 & 1.234 & 5.6 & 789.0 & 12.3 & 4.567
    & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 & 1.234 & 8.901 & 2.3 & 456.7 & 89.0 \\
    Row name
    & 5.678 & 9.0 & 123.4 & 56.7 & 8.901 & 2.345 & 6.7 & 890.1 & 23.4 & 5.678
    & 9.012 & 3.4 & 567.8 & 90.1 & 2.345 & 6.789 & 0.1 & 234.5 & 67.8 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{landscape}
\restoregeometry

\section{Second}
\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Celdor for your thorough answer! I am not really good with Latex, so thanks for the clarifications on the concepts. Your demo code works really well, I am gonna use that to continue with my report.  Cheers!